# iOS Provisioning Profiles - can I change it mid approval process?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile

I have built an app and submitted it to the AppStore. When upgrading to Yosemite I decided I would do a complete refresh of my macbook.

Now I don't have access to the provisioning profile I originally uploaded my app for review with.

The app has been sent back with some iPhone 6 issues.

Am I going to be able to re-upload the app with a new provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You will have to regenerate your App Store provisioning profile with your new key in order for you to Archive the app, but as long as you have a valid provisioning profile for the App Store and a valid key in your keychain maching the one in the app store provisioning profile you'r good to go.